# What is preventing the exploit of the UN’s voting system?

Tags: united-nations

What is preventing a country, say, China, for example, from giving 500 adults 1 square acre of land per 5 people, and giving them ownership of the land, (under threat of invasion and murder if they don’t comply with what China says), and then naming those 100 “countries” independent, signing them up for the UN, and getting an extra 500 votes in the general assembly?

Comment: This makes no sense.  why would the UN then accept those 500 "countries" in the first place???  China has a veto right, not a right to compel admission.  And the US does presumably have a veto right to veto admission, if this falls under Security Council purview.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: [What are the steps to become an independent country once independence has been declared?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25538/19301) and [What does a country need to do get rejected by the UN?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33983/19301)

Comment: This is a ridiculous scenario, but the question is basically: "How does a new country get a seat in the UN General Assembly?"

Comment: Why? General Assembly resolutions have no legal authority.

Comment: The GA has authority over internal matters relevant to the GA, in particular, the GA has the final vote on admission to the GA.

Comment: Downvotes are a bit harsh in my opinion, especially for a 13-year-old. I think it should be kept in mind that too many downvoted questions creates an auto-ban on posting more.

Comment: The US has done something like this with some pacific islands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is preventing China from doing this?

France, the UK, the USA and Russia (and 193 other nations)

Per the UN charter:

> The admission of any such [peace-loving] state to membership in the United Nations will be effected by a decision of the General Assembly upon the recommendation of the Security Council. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_states_of_the_United_Nations))

So if China creates and recognises 500 puppet states it has no consequence whatsoever unless the Security Council recommends that they are admitted to the UN (which requires none of the other permanent members (France, the UK, the USA and Russia) to use their veto) and then a vote in the General Assembly (which in practice will follow the recommendation of the Security council)

So China can't "sign up" these fake nations to the UN,  the other nations need to agree.

Answer (score 3):

Mainly it would be a lack of international recognition by the other countries; there is no way to legally force them to recognize those new countries and allow for their entry at the UN.

Compare this with the Russian backed [Abkhazia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia), [Transnistria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transnistria) and [South Ossetia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Ossetia). In their favour they have that they are more substantial than 500 adults, as a disavantage the international community supports that they are part of another country.

None of them is a member of the UN.

As a curiosity, after World War II a number of republics from the Soviet Union  (Ukraine and Byelorussia) got seats in the general assembly despite not being independent, as a way to "level the playing field" towards the Soviet Union, which had few allies. Of course at this time this prevented the danger of the Soviet Union simply refusing to join the UN due to being totally isolated there.